# SpriteBuilder & CCTexture - copy textures from smart sprite sheet in SpriteBuilder

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have come across a problem when trying to copy textures from smart sprite sheet in SpriteBuilder.

When i copy a sprite.texture it seems to copy the complete smart sprite sheet and not the individual image.

example

If i create a sprite using the image name

```
 CCSprite *redSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Images/Red-Sprite.png"];
```

and use that sprite it works Fine.

However if i

```
    _textureRedSprite = redSprite.texture;
```

it will copy the complete sprite sheet and use that as the texture and not the individual image i require.

any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with / referencing the sprite's texture:

```
_textureRedSprite = redSprite.texture;
```

.. use the sprite's sprite frame which contains references to both the texture as well as the offset and rectangle in the texture atlas for that particular image:

```
CCSpriteFrame* redSpriteFrame = redSprite.spriteFrame;
otherSprite.spriteFrame = redSpriteFrame;
```